# JS Phone mask input

Tags: javascript, inputmask

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Подключаю маску телефона:

```
import Inputmask from "inputmask";
import 'inputmask.phone/dist/inputmask.phone/inputmask.phone.extensions.js';
import 'inputmask.phone/dist/inputmask.phone/phone-codes/phone';
```

Применяю маску к элементу с указанием алиаса телефона:
`Inputmask({alias: 'phone'}).mask(".phone");`
Алиас телефона не применяется. Стандартный алиас datetime работает корректно. В чем может быть проблема?

- Inputmask version 5.0.7
- inputmask.phone 1.0.5

В заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Спасибо, поменял текст на русский. Думал что если написать его на английском языке то вероятность что на него ответят будет больше.